# Proper oracle for proving P^A=PSPACE^A

Tags: complexity-theory

i would like to ask a question about oracles in complexity theory.
What would be a proper language to use as an oracle so i can prove that P^A=PSPACE^A.
I guess that i need a language that would render polynomial space powerless but what language would that be? any suggestions..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try: A = PSPACE.

P with a PSPACE oracle will be just as powerful as PSPACE.
PSPACE with a PSPACE oracle does not increase in capability.